# Is is possible to add property to ImageView using extensions to load image via url?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, kotlin-android-extensions

I created an extension function that downloads the image from URL using `Glide` and loads it into `ImageView`.

```
fun ImageView.loadImageFromUrl(url: String) {
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .into(this)
}
```

What I would like to do is add a property `loadImageFromUrl` to `ImageView` and assign the URL to it.

```
imageView.loadImageFromUrl = "https://sample-url.com/image"
```

I am aware this can be done using `BindingAdapter` from `DataBinding`. Can this functionality be achieved without using `DataBinding`?

Comment: Myclass extends Yourclass;

Comment: Is that the only way? Using inheritance? Can operator overloading be used?

Comment: Which operator?

Comment: Set? I am new to this so please point out if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have no idea where you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view it's a quite odd api but if you really want it you can write:

```kotlin
var ImageView.loadImageFromUrl: String
    get() = ""
    set(value) {
        loadImageFromUrl(value)
    }
```

Comment: I understand that this is not a normal way, but this exactly what I want to learn. Thank you!